# Save AvalonDock layout with dynamic content

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

I am trying to learn the AvalonDock environment in WPF.  I have an anchorable pane that contains a treeview which displays a list of objects (basically contains a name and value).

I also have some document panes that host a UserControl.  I can drag an item from the treeview into a document (UserControl which is basically a WrapPanel) and then drop it, it adds a 2nd user control type (this user control has a textblock bound to 'name' and a textbox bound to 'value') to my control hosted by the document.

Now - I want to be able to save this layout- with the dynamic content created by the drag/drop.

Is this possible?  When using the XmlLayoutSerializer I see the generated xaml has my documents and anchorables, but none of these items have any content.

Should I instead be saving a collection of the objects (i.e. the ObservableCollection I am bound to) and initialize the collection when I want to 'restore' the view?

The intent is to have a view that end-users can modify to display the data they want (from the treeview) and arrange the layout as they see fit.

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an article on CodeProject which describes a solution:
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/719143/avalondock-tutorial-part-load-save-layout

You may also take a look at the Gemini project, which has a much more flexible solution:
https://github.com/tgjones/gemini/
The important stuff is in the Gemini/Framework directory.

It's a pure MVVM solution which keeps all the documents and layout items in the main/shell viewmodel and databinds to it. While saving layout, it asks every viewmodel to save its state and the `DockingManager` state is persisted last. While loading layout, all the state is read first and the viewmodels are recreated in the `LayoutSerializationCallback` event of the AvalonDocks `XmlLayoutSerializer`. This is nice and clean approach, but (AFAIK) it cannot handle a situation when the controls are created purely in XAML and connected to the rest of the application using some kind of messaging (Prism  `EventAggregator` for example).

To solve this kind of problem, you'll need a help from the view which hosts `DockingManager`, ask it for a list of `LayoutAnchorables` and `LayoutDocuments` and save/load their states using the similar mechanism. It's not as elegant and pure MVVM as the original solution, but I found it more flexible. You can wrap everything in a few interfaces and extension methods.

I did something like that for my project and it works great. Might put it on GitHub some day.